# Exchanging data between two Tasks in .NET 6

Tags: .net, multithreading, task, .net-6.0, message-queue

I have two Tasks running independently in my application. One of them is getting some data from a device, and the other one is supposed to
collect that data.

Both of them are "forever loops", so using `await` is not an option for me.

I come from an embedded software background, usually for something like this I would create a queue,
in which one task would enqueue the data while the other task would wait for an item in that queue
and dequeue it for further processing. Usually APIs for this purpose were also available in the
RTOS.

I tried implementing the same, but I found out that the `MessageQueue` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue?view=netframework-4.8.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) is not available in .NET 6. Although I can hack together something similar, I wonder if there is an existing solution that I can use.

Or is my approach to this wrong to begin with?

Comment: There are multiple concrete implementations of the general [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it worked perfectly. :) I was even able to add timeouts and other features I'm familiär with in similar RTOS queues. Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: The built-in, asynchronous producer/consumer queue type is `Channel<T>`, not `MessageQueue. This type works in a similar way to Go's channels. One or more producers write to a Channel through the ChannelWriter interface and one or more consumers read from it through the ChannelReader interface. This is similar to how Go uses different interfaces for readers and writers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> usually for something like this I would create a queue, in which one task would enqueue the data while the other task would wait for an item in that queue and dequeue it for further processing... I wonder if there is an existing solution that I can use.

As Damien pointed out, there are [several implementations of `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace. However:

> I have two Tasks running independently in my application.

If you want an *asynchronous* producer/consumer queue, then the most modern solution is [`System.Threading.Channels`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). Channels are pretty basic but extremely efficient.

There are older but still viable alternatives as well. What you're currently describing is a basic producer/consumer scenario, where `System.Collections.Concurrent` (for synchronous code) or `System.Threading.Channels` (for asynchronous code) is a natural fit. But if your actual scenario is more complex (or grows to be more complex) and you want something more like a pipeline or mesh solution with a bit of an actor feel to it, check out [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution that Damien mentioned worked for me pretty well, and I will also try `System.Threading.Channels` to see if it is more appropriate for my application. Much appreciated :)